# how would i print out multiple columns from a stored procedure in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to print multiple columns in a stored procedure...can anyone please provide me with an example that uses a query. Thank you.

K for example, I have a movie database and I want to find the percentage of the profitable movies of all movies since the year 1960. I have the queires that do that and I ran it on pgADMIN and it works perfectly; however when i try creating a stored procedure, I know I have to use create a type holder as ( yr INTEGER, prnct FLOAT).

So now with that I need to create a stored procedure that would return the two columns one of the year and one of the percent, however how do i that this column is the yr and the next column is prnct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a single row with multiple columns than you can use `record` or `some_table` as the type.

If you have a table like `movie` than you can create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_profitable_movie() RETURNS movie AS
```

If you want to return some arbitrary type, than you'll have to do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_profitable_movie() RETURNS record AS
```

And if you want to return more than 1 row, you have to use the `SETOF` modifier like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_profitable_movie() RETURNS SETOF record AS
```

You can create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION multicolumn_thing() RETURNS record AS $$
DECLARE
    r record;
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, 2, 3 INTO r;
    RETURN r;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And select results from it like this:

```
SELECT
    columns.a,
    columns.b,
    columns.c
FROM multicolumn_thing() AS columns(a int, b int, c int);
```

With a `setof` it's the same but multiple rows ofcourse :)

Comment: so basically it would be like

Comment: So basically it would be like: 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION profit_p_m() RETURNS SETOF record as $$ 

but how would I specifiy which column is which 
can you please provide an example how I would use the record in which I would return two columns and all rows that belong to those columns

Comment: Since I am using it as SETOF record that should display 2 columns and all rows how would i call this in a java program.

would it be something like this.
callm=con.prepareStatement("select * from queryTen() AS");

Comment: @mizz-a: I have added an example of the `RECORD` now.